# How to get access to built-in language services in VSIX?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, com, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I am having trouble with getting access to the default C#-`LanguageService` in `IVsExpansionClient.FormatSpan(IVsTextLines pBuffer, TextSpan[] ts)`. I need a `Source`-Instance of the current `LanguageService` to be able to create an `EditArray` for the incoming Span.
I was able to receive a COM-Object with the following code:

```
pBuffer.GetLanguageServiceID(out var languageServiceId);
var provider = Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider;
var vssp = provider.GetService(typeof(IOleServiceProvider)) as IOleServiceProvider;

var iunknown = new Guid(VSConstants.IID_IUnknown.ToString());
IntPtr ptr;
if (ErrorHandler.Succeeded(vssp.QueryService(ref languageServiceId, ref iunknown, out ptr)))
{
    try
    {
        service = Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(ptr);
        lang = (LanguageService)service;
    }
    finally
    {
        Marshal.Release(ptr);
    }
}
```

But the cast `lang = (LanguageService)service;` fails. I have no idea what type that COM-Object behind `service` is. So my question is, how do I get the current LanguageService of an open editor?

I have taken parts of the code from here:
https://github.com/microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/blob/346f5b0289e5fb8de639ba96fb10703df06cd22d/WPFDesigner_XML/WPFDesigner_XML/ViewModel.cs#L275

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you can create a [new issue](https://github.com/microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/issues) to ask for some solution about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The language services implement a number of different interfaces, you'd be then trying to query it for whatever interface you want. You mentioned C#, and in our case we don't actually derive from the package framework LanguageService at all, so that cast would fail.

You may want to clarify in your question what you're trying to achieve, since that's not exactly clear to me.